# Getting values of JTextFields from one class to another class within same package?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jtextfield

I want to use the values of JTextFields from one class in another class within the same package.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please rephrase your question !! I hope u want to access one class's textfield's value in other class's textfield.

```
class Class1 
{
      JTextField field1;
      public String getFieldText()
      {
            return field1.getText();
      }
}
class Class2
{
      JTextField field2;
      Class2(Class1 c1)
      {
            field2.setText(c1.getFieldText());
      }
}
```

Comment: actually I have many classes...
I want to use the values of JTextFields which  are in one separate class  which is an Applet(consider it as First class)...ok

now I ve another class(consider it as Second class) and i want to get those values of JTextField
which are in Class First..
.

I have used getText() by using the object of Class First 

but when I m creating Object/reference of that class First within  
class Second then it call class First also
and I don't want it.